# Cómo hago para enviar un archivo pdf creado con fpdf a un correo?

Tags: php, phpmailer, fpdf

les cuento no tengo mucha experiencia en programación, si me pueden explicar o mostrarme un codigo para guiarme a realizarlo, la aplicación ya me deja generar el pdf sin problema, ahora falta es enviarlo a un correo apenas este sea generado, este es el codigo que tengo para generarlo:

```
$fecha1=$_POST['fecha_ini_pdf'];
$fecha2=$_POST['fecha_fin_pdf'];
$mens1=$_POST['men_pdf'];
$jor=$_POST['jornadapdf'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM detalles_mensajeria where mensajero = '$mens1' and date(fecha_entrega) BETWEEN '$fecha1' and '$fecha2' and jornada = '$jor' order by id_detalle";

$resultado = $mysql->query($query);

$pdf = new PDF('L');
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232); //color de fondo
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
//$pdf->Cell(20,6,'id detalle',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(25,8,'Fecha registro',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(25,8,'Fecha Entrega',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,8,'Genera',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(27,8,'Mensajero',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(21,8,'Solicita',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,8,'Empresa',1,0,'C',1);
//$pdf->Cell(30,8,'Contacto',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(47,8,utf8_decode('Dirección'),1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(17,8,utf8_decode('Teléfono'),1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(9,8,utf8_decode('Geo.'),1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(47,8,'Detalle Labor',1,0,'C',1); // 47 ancho, 6 alto, texto, 1 borde, 1 salto de linea, C centrado, 1 relleno
$pdf->Cell(14,8,'Recibido',1,1,'C',1);      // Cell(ancho, Alto, texto, borde, salto de linea, alineacion de texto)


$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',7);
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
{
    //$pdf->Cell(20,6,utf8_decode($row['id_detalle']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25,6,$row['fecha_registro'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25,6,$row['fecha_entrega'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(20,6,utf8_decode($row['empresa_toro']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(27,6,utf8_decode($row['mensajero']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(21,6,utf8_decode($row['empleado']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,utf8_decode($row['empresa_contacto']),1,0,'C');
    //$pdf->Cell(30,6,utf8_decode($row['contacto']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(47,6,utf8_decode($row['dir_contacto']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(17,6,$row['tel_contacto'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(9,6,$row['ubicacion'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(47,6,utf8_decode($row['observacion']),1,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(14,6,$row['id_estado_mensajeria'],1,1,'C');

}
// GENERAR EL REPORTE Output
//$pdf->Output(); 
$pdf->Output('D'); // lo genera y permite abrirlo
//$pdf->Output('F','mensajeria.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

este es el codigo el cual me genera el pdf, no me da errores, pero no me llega al correo

```
require '../../../librerias/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$fecha1=$_POST['fecha_ini_pdf'];
$fecha2=$_POST['fecha_fin_pdf'];
$mens1=$_POST['men_pdf'];
$jor=$_POST['jornadapdf'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM detalles_mensajeria where mensajero = '$mens1' and date(fecha_entrega) BETWEEN '$fecha1' and '$fecha2' and jornada = '$jor' order by id_detalle";

$resultado = $mysql->query($query);

$pdf = new PDF('L');
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232); //color de fondo
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
//$pdf->Cell(20,6,'id detalle',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(25,8,'Fecha registro',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(25,8,'Fecha Entrega',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,8,'Genera',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(27,8,'Mensajero',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(21,8,'Solicita',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,8,'Empresa',1,0,'C',1);
//$pdf->Cell(30,8,'Contacto',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(47,8,utf8_decode('Dirección'),1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(17,8,utf8_decode('Teléfono'),1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(9,8,utf8_decode('Geo.'),1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(47,8,'Detalle Labor',1,0,'C',1); // 47 ancho, 6 alto, texto, 1 borde, 1 salto de linea, C centrado, 1 relleno
//$pdf->Cell(14,8,'Recibido',1,1,'C',1);        // Cell(ancho, Alto, texto, borde, salto de linea, alineacion de texto)


$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',7);
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
{
    //$pdf->Cell(20,6,utf8_decode($row['id_detalle']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25,6,$row['fecha_registro'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25,6,$row['fecha_entrega'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(20,6,utf8_decode($row['empresa_toro']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(27,6,utf8_decode($row['mensajero']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(21,6,utf8_decode($row['empleado']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,utf8_decode($row['empresa_contacto']),1,0,'C');
    //$pdf->Cell(30,6,utf8_decode($row['contacto']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(47,6,utf8_decode($row['dir_contacto']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(17,6,$row['tel_contacto'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(9,6,$row['ubicacion'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(47,6,utf8_decode($row['observacion']),1,0,'L');
    //$pdf->Cell(14,6,$row['id_estado_mensajeria'],1,1,'C');

}

$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->Mailer="smtp";
$mail->Helo = "www.gmail.com"; //Muy importante para que llegue a hotmail y otros
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->Host="smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port=25; //depende de lo que te indique tu ISP. El default es 25, pero nuestro ISP lo tiene puesto al 26
$mail->Username="****@gmail.com";
$mail->Password="********";
$mail->From="***@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName="Mensajeria";
$mail->Timeout=60;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->AddAddress('pruebas@gmail.com'); 
$pdf->Output('D'); // lo genera y permite abrirlo
$p = $pdf->Output('','S');
$mail->AddStringAttachment($p,'reporte.pdf','base64');
```